# Common.Logging "void Error( object message, Exception exception );" not logging the "Exception"

Tags: c#, nlog, common.logging

I'm using Common.Logging with the NLog adapter.

http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/logging.html

I'm calling this method:

```
void Error( object message, Exception exception );
```

The text of the "message" shows up in the Logs (a txt-file and in the EventLog), but the details about the exception do not.  Not even the ex.Message.

Am I missing something?

How do I get the details about the Exception to show up.  Do I have to just tack it on the "object message"?  I guess having the overload'ed method with the exception, I thought there would be some auto-logging.

My NLog.config is fairly simple.

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="MyFile.log.txt"/>
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
    <target xsi:type="EventLog"
             name="eventLog" 
             source="MySource"
       eventId="555"
             log="Application"
                     />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Error" writeTo="eventLog" />
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="logfile"/>
  </rules>

</nlog>
```

EDIT:

Ok...based on the Sergey answer, I just roided up my setup:

```
layout="${longdate}|${level}|${callsite}|${logger}|${threadid}|${windows-identity:domain=false}__${message} ${exception:format=message,stacktrace:separator=*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation, [default layout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layouts) is

```
${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}
```

You should specify [`${exception}`](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer) layout renderer to write exception info. E.g. set following layout for targets which should write exceptions:

```
${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}${newline}${exception}
```

If you want all targets to have same layout, you can move its definition to variable:

```
<variable name="verbose" 
          value="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}${newline}${exception}" />
<targets>
   <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" layout="${verbose}" fileName="log.txt" />
   <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${verbose}"/>
   <target name="eventLog" xsi:type="EventLog" layout="${verbose}"
           source="MySource" eventId="555" log="Application" />
</targets>
<rules>
   <logger name="*" minLevel="Error" writeTo="eventLog" />
   <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="console,logfile" />
 </rules>
```

Comment: Ok.  That was my disconnect.  There is a default layout.  Makes sense.  I had wired up my database-logger with the more advanced layout, but not my event-log and text-file loggers.  Thx.

Comment: Superplus for the reusable "verbose" variable.

Comment: @granadaCoder yep, cool feature. Also you can use logger which writes to several targets - as you can see, I've combined console and file targets